# Silverlight: Difficulty with ScrollViewer (again)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

The following XAML works fine:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
         <ListBox x:Name="StoryListBox"/>
</Grid>
```

The `ListBox` scrolls appropriately when there is too much content to fit on a single screen.

However, I modify the XAML as follows, and it breaks:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox x:Name="LoadingMessage"  Text="Loading..." Grid.Row="0" />
    <ListBox x:Name="StoryListBox" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Button x:Name="LoadMoreStories" Content="Load More Stories" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

</Grid>
```

Now, the `ListBox` only scrolls down a tiny bit, even though it has overflowed content.

How did I mess it up?

**Update**: I also tried the following, but it still doesn't work:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <StackPanel x:Name="Loading">
        <TextBox Text="Loading..." />
        <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Style="{StaticResource PerformanceProgressBar}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="StoryListBox" />
            <Button x:Name="LoadMoreStories" Content="Load More Stories" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

It has the same issue of the `ListBox` only scrolling down a tiny bit.

Comment: Here it seems to be working with no issues. Could you post a self-contained sample (with sample data, for example)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Only caveat to this solution is that "Load More" button will always be at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I'd like the "Load More" button to be at the bottom of everything, after the user scrolls past all the content.

Answer (score 0):

It scrolls properly but the size of List box is bigger than page. Try setting the size explicite.

```
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="500">
            <TextBox x:Name="LoadingMessage"  Text="Loading..." Grid.Row="0" />
            <ListBox x:Name="StoryListBox" Grid.Row="0" >
                <ListBoxItem Content="a"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="b"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="c"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="d"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="e"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="f"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="g"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="h"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="i"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="j"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="k"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="l"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="1"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="2"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="3"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="4"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="5"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="6"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="7"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="8"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="9"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="10"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="11"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="12"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="13"></ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="14"></ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
           </StackPanel>
```